# Adding subgrid results in empty box on form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, subgrid

I'm trying to add a subgrid to the Contact form to show related opportunities, but nothing shows up on screen. Nothing shows up on screen. Can you help me diagnose what's wrong here? All the searching I've done leads to assistance with getting related Activities set up.

As far as I can tell, I have the grid set up properly:

[image: Properties dialog for the Opportunity subgrid]

However, the subgrid space on the form itself is empty - not even the menus, column headers, or scroll bars show up.

The subgrid is the empty box between the bottom of the correctly-functioning address label report iframe ("Contact preferences:") and the correctly-functioning Internal Strategy field (blocked out for client privacy).

[image: Person form showing the empty subgrid box]

Comment: version of IE? Rollup installed?

Comment: IE 9.0.8112 & 10.0.9200; CRM 2011 Update Rollup 13

Comment: are you doing anything custom with the sub-grid in javascript (eg adding a custom view)?  if so, you may want to call a subgrid.Refresh() on it. Also, are there any plugins running on retrieveMultiple in your environment?  If so, and if they are failing, then you may get results like this.